# Making an object return to start point in corona

Tags: events, lua, coronasdk, collision

So I have a function which runs if someone is holding a button (an object moves). But I also have this collision between that object and another static one, when the first object hits the second one, it gets sent back to the start point. But the problem is that when I keep holding the button to move the object. It doesn't send it back to start when it collides. It just messes up.

This is the code I have for the hold button function:

```
local holding = false
function enterFrameListener()
if holding then
 transition.to( cube, {time = 0, x= cube.x - 5} )
end
end

function touchHandler( event )
if event.phase == "began" then
    display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( event.target )
    event.target.isFocus = true
    Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", enterFrameListener )
    holding = true
elseif event.target.isFocus then
    if event.phase == "moved" then
    elseif event.phase == "ended" then
        holding = false
        Runtime:removeEventListener( "enterFrame", enterFrameListener )
        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( nil )
        event.target.isFocus = false
    end
end
return true
end
leftbutton:addEventListener( "touch", touchHandler )
```

This is the code I have for the collision:

```
function onCollision( event )

if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
  transition.cancel( )
  transition.moveTo( cube, {time = 0, x = 35, y = 100} )
end
end
redblock:addEventListener( "collision", onCollision )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert a `return true` at the end of the `onCollision(event)` function as below:

```
function onCollision( event )
   if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
     transition.cancel( )
     transition.moveTo( cube, {time = 0, x = 35, y = 100} )
   end
   return true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Make object as bullet.
There is a property in corona.
isBullet=true
will make your physics object as bullet so it'll check collision for several times in a second.
Then this event can thrown, otherwise it'll not raise that event.